# Left side tab is missing in Logcat android studio. How to get that back

Tags: android-studio, logcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuHUZ.png)

How to get that menu bar back, Please answer my question experts, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just go to View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat.
That's it.
Shortcut for logcat : Alt + 6

Comment: thanks for commenting my question..still my menu in logcat is missing